# XAML loading error using contentProperty

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am reading up more on XAML and I have created an XML file and want to load it. It all works but when I use the ContentProperty attribute and more importantly I remove the Company.Employees tags from the XML file, I get the error "cannot add to Company" when loading the xml file.

The code is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <Company Name="BBC" xmlns="clr-namespace:XamlLoading;assembly=XamlLoading">
  <Company.Owner> 
    <Person Name="John" Age="49"/>
  </Company.Owner>

  <!--<Company.Employees>
    <Person Name="Dave" Age="66" />
     <Person Name="Paul" Age="45"/>
  </Company.Employees>-->

 <Person Name="Dave" Age="66" />
 <Person Name="Paul" Age="45"/>
</Company>
```

```cs
[ContentProperty("Employees")]
public class Company 
{
    public Company()
    {
        Employees = new List<Person>();
    }

    public Person Owner { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Employees { get; set; }
}


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(@"..\..\company.xml"))
        {

            Company c = (Company)XamlReader.Load(fs); * ERROR HERE

            Console.WriteLine(c.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(c.Owner);

            foreach (var item in c.Employees)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} : ", item);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you update to the latest version of .NET. Your code works great for me.

This is a very interesting case study for XAML. I have never seen it used this way before. Typically XAML is used like HTML markup for declaratively defining a user interface. [Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Blend_Overview.aspx) is a WYSIWYG editor for creating user interfaces by generating XAML.

You have demonstrated some interesting potential for realizing data from xml using the XamlReader.

Comment: Thanks Josh, I would love to take credit but I cannot quite remember where I had seen it being used.

Comment: Incidentally, have you ever tried using XmlSerializer? It ends up being fairly similar to what you are trying to use the XamlReader for here.